# Using getline with own class C++

Tags: c++

Sorry,I create an own class of `string` with overloading operators and function `at()`. I created it for inluding it in another my class. I don't have problems with anything except one.

My error is :

```
std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>&std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>&,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)': could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'String'
```

The problem is in `getline()` function. This function doesn't take MY `string` as an argument `str` .Can I find another close variant to `getline()` for reading my file with using `MY string`?

Why can't `getline()` work with MY string, why does it wait for some real string?

My function is:

```
void City::readRecordings(char *fileName, char *num, std::vector<string> lines)
{

    string str;
    //std::ifstream fin(fileName);
    readRecord >>str;
    int readCount = 0;
    int n = atoi(num);
    readRecord.open(fileName);
    while (!readRecord.eof())
    {
        std::getline(readRecord, str);/*here is Error, It can't use my String str , it waits for usual string*/
        readCount++;
        lines.push_back(str);
    }

    if (0 == readCount)
    {
        std::cout << "ERROR: The file, which you are trying to open, is empty or it stops out" << end;
        exit(-1);
    }
    if (n > readCount)
    {
        std::cout << "!Warning!" << end;
        std::cout << "You want to read  " << n << " recordings" << " But AVAILABLE: " << readCount << " recordings" << end;
        printRecordsFromFile(readCount, lines);
    }
    else
    {
        printRecordsFromFile(n, lines);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's the same reason the sky is blue: because `std::getline()`'s second parameter is a `std::string` (well, `std::basic_string`, to be pedantic). That's what `std::getline()` is.

Comment: So what's _from 'String'_ mentioned in the error message. Your own stuff?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, I made some realization for MY string

Comment: @SamVarshavchik And can't I find another variants except `getline()`

Comment: Because `std::string` is not a `String` and a `String` is not a `std::string`. C++ 101.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are welcome to write your own `getline` function that uses your string class:

```
std::istream&
std::getline(std::istream& input_stream, My_String& s, char delimiter = '\n')
{
  //...
  return input_stream;
}
```

There are many advantages to using `std::string` instead of developing your own string class.